# Cannot see sent or received messages on any application on my Nokia Lumia 525

Tags: sms, reset

This has happened twice even after I hard reset my phone. I cannot see any texts I receive or send even though the other person can see my sent texts. On applications like Viber, Whatsapp, Facebook and every other application, notifications appear on top but when I click them, there is no refreshed message. Similarly if someone has called me or missed called me, there will be no notification or update on the missed calls page.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce in my phone.

Comment: Windows Phone 8 or 8.1?